# Sum of an elemnt in option section of codeigniter cart

Tags: codeigniter, cart

Hello All Knowledgeable persons in codeigniter,

I am using codeigniter cart system.

Here's is the structure of my codeigniter cart

```
$data = array(
                'id'      => $id,
                'qty'     => $qty,
                'price'   => $price,
                'name'    => $name,
                'options' => array(
                                  'picture'=>$img,
                                  'item_slug'=>$slug,
                                  'item_color'=>$color,
                                  'item_size'=>$size,
                                  'unit_price'=>$price,
                                  'order_type'=>$order_type,
                                  'product_type'=>$pro_type,
                                  'unit_discount' => 0.00,
                                  'total_discount' => 0.00,
                                  'discount_type' => '',
                                )
                                );
```

Now I want to get the total total_discount on the cart, which i can do by a code-snippet like this

```
$tot_discount = 0.00;
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $ci)
       {
          $tot_discount = floatval($tot_discount + $ci['options']['total_discount'];
       }
```

Now my question is, is there any inbuilt cart function to get sum of any numeric field of the options section in codeigniter? say like $this->cart->total() gives the total price of the cart.

Or I need to use the above code snippet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While working with cart library in codeigniter, there are some fix parameters for cart that you need to set and some are optional.

Fixed Parameters

```
'id'      => $id,
'qty'     => $qty,
'price'   => $price,
'name'    => $name
```

Optional Parameters

```
'options' => array();
```

Actually options variable holds additional product specific information as you have specified and they may change subject to your business requirement. Now we have a common function total() as mentioned below:

```
$this->cart->total()
```

If you'll read the method definition then you'll find that it utilizes 'price' parameter for getting the total cart amount. Now as you have declared the 'total_discount' inside 'options' array, so there is a custom business requirement. So you can utilize the "total()" method definition to create your own function like "totalDiscount" because it varies product to product.